# how add inside a scrollView webView and buttons in swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, scrollview

How add inside a scrollView webView and buttons ?
i tried this, it resize webview but not scrolling

```
 let output = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.offsetHeight;")
            let contentHeight = output?.toInt()
            let conHeight:CGFloat = CGFloat(contentHeight!)
            var frame = self.webView.frame
            frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.webView.frame.size.width, conHeight)
            self.webView.frame = frame
```

Comment: A web view is also a kind of scroll view so you need to be careful when putting scroll views inside scroll views – to be sure which view gets the scroll events. Could you also add what is the content height and what is the height of the scroll view?

Comment: I set webview (srcollView.scrollEnabled and userInteractionEnabled) to false